# How to get the count of same rows from two tab deliminated file with awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two tab deliminated files

```
File1.tab
100 ABC
300 CDE

File2.tab
399 GSA
300 CDE
```

I want awk command to return 1 because row '300 CDE' is common in both file.

Comment: Did yo try anything?

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so please do add so and let us know then.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - Please [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on asking a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost hate to encourage laziness by answering a question with so little effort put into it, but did you try [`grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html)?

```
$: grep -c -f File1.tab File2.tab
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If lines are unique per file you can use `grep`

```
grep -f File1.tab File2.tab | wc -l
```